# How to draw multiple rectangles with mouse on an image?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I am trying to build a WinForm application that will load an image file from an openfiledialog and load it into either a panel or picturebox.  I want to be able to draw multiple rectangles with the left mouse button and have them stay on the image.  I have been successful in getting a single rectangle at a time on the actual form but not on an image inside a panel/picturebox.  Does anyone know of a resource that would help me understand how to achieve this?

This is the code that allows me to draw a single resizable rectangle on the form, but when I change the mouse events from `form1_MouseEvent` to `panel1_MouseEvent` it does nothing..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Temporary_Name_Utility
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Rectangle myRectangle;
        bool draw = false;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog myFile = new OpenFileDialog();
                myFile.Filter = "Image Files(*.img, *.bmp) |*.img; *.bmp;";
                myFile.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";

                if (myFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(myFile.FileName);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error loading the selected file.  Original error: " + error.Message);

            }

        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            myRectangle = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
            this.Invalidate();
        }


        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if(draw)
            {
                using(Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, myRectangle);
                }
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                myRectangle = new Rectangle(myRectangle.Left, myRectangle.Top, Math.Min(e.X - myRectangle.Left, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width - myRectangle.Left), Math.Min(e.Y - myRectangle.Top, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height - myRectangle.Top));
            }
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code you already have.  The question in its current form is off-topic.

Comment: @LarsTech, how is it off topic?  I'm asking for someone to suggest/point me to resources to help me understand how to accomplish this..

Comment: How about google searching for "how to draw on picturebox c#"? I think first result will be what you looking for.

Comment: @Renius, please dont take this as rude but c'mon..do you think I didn't try google first??  What I keep finding on google isn't giving me the help I need which is why I have turned to SO to see if anyone is aware of articles/blogs/etc that are easily barried in the results or looked over by searching the wrong keywords..

Comment: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`

Comment: @LarsTech, ok I see what you're saying but I think that's a little silly.  I'm not asking who thinks what site is the best, I'm asking for help to find resources..

Comment: You have a StackOverflow of users willing to be your resource.  Just give us a question we can answer.  Show your code and explain where the problem is.

Comment: I don't see a paint event.

Comment: Maybe I should have prefaced my question by saying I don't know what the heck I'm doing and if you could please ELI5.

Comment: `draw` is never true.

Comment: @LarsTech, ha! ok good catch.  I changed draw to be true in the declaration and in the paint event.  Now I a red rectangle appears in the middle of the image!  But I don't want it to automatically draw it for me, I want to be able to draw it where ever in the picturebox with the mouse.. what else am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got some working code: This allows the user to draw as many rectangles as wanted with the mouse inside of the picturebox.

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rectangle_Utility
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point startPos;
        Point currentPos;
        bool drawing;
        List<Rectangle> myRectangles = new List<Rectangle>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }

        #region Menu Tool Strip
        private void selectFileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Initiate new OpenFileDialog
                //Filter for img and bmp files
                //Start looking in root of c:
                OpenFileDialog myFile = new OpenFileDialog();
                myFile.Filter = "Image Files(*.img, *.bmp) |*.img; *.bmp;";
                myFile.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";

                //Set background image of pictureBox to file selected through OpenFileDialog
                if (myFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(myFile.FileName);

                }
            }

            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error loading the selected file.  Original error: " + error.Message);

            }
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void clearAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void zoomToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void undoLastActionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void redoLastActionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        #endregion

        #region Rectangle

        private Rectangle getRectangle()
        {
            return new Rectangle(
                Math.Min(startPos.X, currentPos.X),
                Math.Min(startPos.Y, currentPos.Y),
                Math.Abs(startPos.X - currentPos.X),
                Math.Abs(startPos.Y - currentPos.Y));
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                currentPos = startPos = e.Location;
                drawing = true;
            }

        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            currentPos = e.Location;
            if (drawing) pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (myRectangles.Count > 0) e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(Pens.Black, myRectangles.ToArray());
            if (drawing) e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, getRectangle());
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawing)
            {
                drawing = false;
                var rect = getRectangle();
                if (rect.Width > 0 && rect.Height > 0) myRectangles.Add(rect);
                pictureBox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a graphic from image and use that graphic to draw the rectangle so that the rectangle will be drawn in the image.

```
Graphics newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
newGraphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), rectangles);
```

Comment: Don't forget to call .Dispose() on your graphics instance once you are done using it or you will leak GDI handles until the garbage collector gets around to cleaning up your instances.

Comment: This creates an isolated in-memory `Graphics` object, draws a rectangle in it, then throws it away. It will have no effect on the screen or WinForm application.